# Specifying resource requirements for chronos jobs

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

Is it possible to specify resource requirements (cpu, mem, ...) when scheduling a job in [chronos](https://github.com/airbnb/chronos) via the REST API? I [found](https://github.com/airbnb/chronos/blob/master/docs/CONFIG.md) there are configuration options that allow specifying general resource requirements for each task but I wonder whether it is possible to do this per job.

Comment: What kind of jobs are you scheduling? In other words, can you provide more distinction between "job" and "task"? If the jobs are composed of tasks being run on another distributed framework (e.g., Hadoop, Spark, etc.) then it's generally best to specify resource requirements for those via a meta-framework such as Marathon or Aurora.

Comment: By job I mean launching an "external" process/command. I'm specifically thinking about launching R (http://www.r-project.org/) processes for which I may know resource requirements in advance.

Comment: There are highly active discussions on the implementation of external containerizers. Once those interfaces are solid, building something on top of those that cover your task seems reasonably easy to do.

Comment: To add what Till mentioned, integrations with Linux containers are probably more of what you're looking for... Check out using Docker with Marathon on Mesos: http://mesosphere.io/2013/09/26/docker-on-mesos/  Marathon may be more of what you want, more so than Chronos  https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's possible to restrict resources per task, but you have to use `cgroups` isolation on mesos slaves. However it seems that Chronos API [doesn't support it yet (see github issue for more details)](https://github.com/airbnb/chronos/issues/111). Mesos is being developed quite rapidly, be sure to check that it is supported in your version.